# An application of the Baire category theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, baire-category, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology

In the highlighted sentence, $ K_n$ is a closed subset of $V^o$, which is the polar of $V$ and so is compact in the weak-* topology by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem. Therefore, $K_n$ is weak-* compact. Theorem 1.3.13 refers to the Baire category theorem. Since $K_n$ is locally compact, we only need that $K_n$ is Hausdorff. Here, how can I know that $K_n$ is Hausdorff so that I may apply the category theorem? Or, is there something that I misunderstood? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I guess the space $\mathcal X^*\supset V^o$ is Hausdorff it weak-$*$ topology, because for any distinct elements $\varphi$, $\psi$ of $\mathcal X^*$ there exists a point $x\in X$ such that $\varphi(x)\ne\psi(x)$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yeah, thank you so much for the reply. Actually, I understood by myself some hours ago, but will not delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The weak$^\ast$ topology is Hausdorff and so are all its subspaces. So it's no issue.